# Tomcat - How exactly context path matching works?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

Suppose I have two Spring webapps deployed to the same Tomcat server instance:

**A:**

`ROOT.war, context = /`

```
@Controller
class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/api/someMethod")
    public String someMethod() {
        //..
    }

    @RequestMapping("/api/v1/someMethod")
    public String someMethod() {
        //..
    }
}
```

**B:**

`api#v1.war, context = /api/v1/`

```
@Controller
class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/someMethod")
    public String someMethod() {
        //..
    }
}
```

Which web application will be used to process the following HTTP requests?

`GET http://<hostname>/api/someMethod`

`GET http://<hostname>/api/v1/someMethod`

`GET http://<hostname>/api/v1/nonexistentMethod`

As you can see the second HTTP request matches both apps. I have tried to find answer in [Tomcat docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html), but found none. Where is specified how context path matching works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Servlet 3.0 Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf)

**10.1 Web Applications Within Web Servers**

> A Web application is rooted at a specific path within a Web server.
> For example, a  catalog application could be located at
> http://www.mycorp.com/catalog. All requests that start with this
> prefix will be routed to the ServletContext which represents the
> catalog application.
>
> A servlet container can establish rules for
> automatic generation of Web applications. For example a  ~user/
> mapping could be used to map to a Web application based at
> /home/user/public_html/

**12.1 Use of URL Paths**

> Upon receipt of a client request, the Web container determines the
> Web application  to which to forward it. **The Web application selected
> must have the longest context  path that matches the start of the
> request  URL**. The matched part of the URL is the  context path when
> mapping to servlets. The Web container next must locate the servlet
> to process the request using the path  mapping procedure described
> below. The path used for mapping to a servlet is the request URL from
> the request object minus the context path and the path parameters.
> The URL path mapping rules below are used in order. **The first
> successful match is used with no further matches attempted**:
>
> 1. The container will try to find an exact match of the path of the request to the path of the servlet. A successful match selects the
>    servlet.
> 2. The container will recursively try to ma tch the longest path-pre fix. This is done  by stepping down the path tree a directory at a
>    time, using the  ’ / ’  character as a  path separator. The longest
>    match  determines the servlet selected.
> 3. If the last segment in the URL path contains an extension (e.g.  .jsp ), the servlet  container will try to match a servlet that
>    handles requests for the extension. An  extension is defined as the
>    part of  the last segment after the last  ’ . ’  character.
> 4. Versions of this specification prior to 2.5 made use of  these mapping techniques as a suggestion rather than a  requirement,
>    allowing servlet containers to each have  their different schemes for
>    mapping client requests to  servlets.
> 5. If neither of the previous three rules re sult in a servlet match, the container will  attempt to serve content appropriate for the
>    resource requested. If a "default"  servlet is defined for the
>    application, it will be used. Many containers provide an  implicit
>    default servlet for serving content.

Also [Tomcat Request Process Flow](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/architecture/requestProcess/request-process.png) might be useful